# How to POST JSON and a file to web service with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I send a POST request with AngularJS? The JSON part is required but the file is not. I have tried this based on other blog posts but it does not work. I get a *Bad request 400 error*.

```
var test = {
  description:"Test",
  status: "REJECTED"
};

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data', angular.toJson(test));

return $http.post('/servers', fd, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  }
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to send in a single request both an encoded file _and_ JSON content? Can you clarify on the flow you want to get?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Yes that is correct, all in one request. I have created a Java Spring backend that takes a JSON part which is required, and a file part that is optional. I have a form where the user enter data, the model is then converted to Json by the angular.toJson(..) and then I want to post that. The user can also choose to upload a file in the same form.

Comment: Hmmm, this can be a little work or a lot of what, what browsers do you have to support?

Comment: I will not care about ancient browswers. People using my web page should have a html5 browser.

Comment: `FormData` is definitely the way to go then, you seem halfway through, you are appending the JSON data to the form but not the file, you should call `fd.append` on your file (or create a `Blob` from it) and send it. (See [this tutorial](http://goo.gl/Fv4YTp) on FormData, if you have any feedback on it I'd like to hear too :)). Once you set it up you still need to support Multipart in Spring. This requires http://goo.gl/iYguqz . I'd also use normal XHR and not `$http` for this to be honest,newer versions of Angular probably fixed some of he old problems Angular had with FormData in AJAX though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The backend is working properly, it works when I test with Curl. But on the client side (in the console) I get bad request 400. The file part is optional. You can do a multipart with only the JSON part. I don't know why it doesn't work. It seems like the Content-Type inside the first multipart is missing, is that the cause of error? How do I add it. Could you give an example with AngularJS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've tested your code with a simple Spring backend and it works fine:

```java
@Controller
public class FileController {

  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value = "/data/fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String postFile(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file,
                       @RequestParam(value="data") Object data) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("data = " + data);

    return "OK!";
  }
}
```

I've used your client side code with angular v1.1.5:

```js
var test = {
  description:"Test",
  status: "REJECTED"
};

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('data', angular.toJson(test));

//remove comment to append a file to the request
//var oBlob = new Blob(['test'], { type: "text/plain"});
//fd.append("file", oBlob,'test.txt');

return $http.post('/data/fileupload', fd, {
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': undefined
  }
});
```

The request looks like this (copied from Chrome console network tab):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/data/fileupload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
POST /data/fileupload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEGiRWBFzWY6xwelb
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
...
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryEGiRWBFzWY6xwelb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"description":"Test","status":"REJECTED"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryEGiRWBFzWY6xwelb--
```

Response 200 OK, and the console outputs the expected: `{"description":"Test","status":"REJECTED"}`

Comment: Hmm...@RequestParam you say, why isn't @RequestPart correct in this case. Because that is what I have in my app. I will change and check if it works then...but it would be useful for me to know why I should use that instead:)

Comment: And the data param, can I instead declare the correct type instead? Or do I have to cast it from Object inside the controller?

Comment: First, I should mention that I'm using `@Bean public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {return new CommonsMultipartResolver();}` in my Spring config. Not sure about `@RequestPart` vs `@RequestParam`. It shouldn't be a problem declaring the data param as the correct type, I just used Object for simplicity.

Comment: I have this in the XML `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!--Max upload size is 8 MB-->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="8192000" />
    </bean>` but I don't understand how I can declare @RequestParam("cat") Cat cat, instead of Object? It doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Since the data part is in JSON, I want to convert that to the Domain object on the server side automatically...as when I use `@RequestBody` and `@ResponseBody`

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem - but `@RequestParam("cat") Cat cat` wont't work with the data from the example (no param named "cat") - did you mean `@RequestParam("data") Cat cat`? That should work with something like `class Cat { public String description; public String status; }`

Comment: Yes, I ment that. I don't manage to get it working, have you done that before?

Comment: I have it working on my project, but it's someone else that's configured Spring so I'm not sure how it's done. We use Jackson2 as an HttpMessageConverter. I'm sorry I can't be of any more help

Comment: I am having some great trouble with this method. I posted a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173102/weird-error-between-2-environments-formdata-bug-with-http-post-angularjs-r

Answer (score -3):

You can post the JSON content directly in the POST data.

```
$http.post(URI, JSON.stringify(test));
```

Depending on the API specification, you might have to add the content-type.

```
$http.post(URI, JSON.stringify(test), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
```

Comment: Sorry about that, got thrown off by the "JSON part is required but the file is not".