# Angular POST multipart/form-data with application/json & text/csv

Tags: json, angularjs, post, file-upload, multipartform-data

**PROBLEM**

Trying to send a multipart/formdata post request with a file upload and model data in JSON.
Not sure why there are not much working references, couldn't make work the ones which are there. 
Might be doing something wrong as well or making it more complicated too.

**REFS TRIED**

- [uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/)
- [a nice explanation about boundary and multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082243)
- [some so question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28023703)

[**QUICK FIDDLE WITH MY TRIES**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/2849/)

**QUESTION**

Somehow json content on my post request payload doesn't seem to contain Content-Type: application/json identified automatically.

Even setting the content-type as undefined/false for the POST didnt work.
Need some suggestion on what would be the problem or how to fix this?

**NETWORK LOG FOR FIDDLE UPLOAD**

Request Headers

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Length:361
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7NukqN6GtRwugBSJ
```

Request Payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7NukqN6GtRwugBSJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv


------WebKitFormBoundary7NukqN6GtRwugBSJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"name":"a good name","comments":"some comments"}
------WebKitFormBoundary7NukqN6GtRwugBSJ--
```

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203145/how-to-post-json-and-a-file-to-web-service-with-angular

Comment: thanks. its exactly the similar thing in fiddle posted, but its not sending that content-type for the json content. could you take a look at the fiddle and see whether i'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.Try using blob and You can set the type in the blob as application/json. You can initialize the blob with your values and it worked for me.

Comment: Ex: new Blob([{"key":"value"}],{"type":"application/json");

Comment: Please add the code in your answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you make a "multipart/form-data" request, then automatically, the "application/JSON" header will be left out. You cannot have both in the same request. The two post requests are mutually exclusive.

Comment: `Accept:` is a request header used for content negotiation by the server, informing the server what kind of response is supported by the client. It does not describe the content-type of the request payload.