# Angular FIle upload Custom headers for upload all

Tags: angularjs

I want to add custom headers to a file before Uploading. Both methods below are not working:

```
   $scope.uploadallman = function (qID) {
    alert(qID);

   uploader.headers = { QuestionID: qID };

    //item.headers = {
    //    MyHeader: qID,
    //};
    uploader.uploadAll();
}
```

Comment: What is uploader?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best solution, but it's the way I do it and it's working.

```
function _uploadFile(resourceURL, file) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var config = {};
    config.headers = {};
    config.transformRequest = angular.identity;
    config.headers['Content-Type'] = undefined;

    // config.headers['MyCustomHeaderKey'] = MyCustomHeaderValue; // Optional

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    // formData.append('myCustomFormDataAttributeKey', myCustomFormDataAttributeValue); // Optional

    $http.post(resourceURL, formData, config)
        .success(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function (err, status) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

This is very good topic about the file upload in Angular:

[How to POST JSON and a file to web service with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203145/how-to-post-json-and-a-file-to-web-service-with-angular)