# how to send file with json object to webservice to rest webservice from angular 2

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

[How to POST JSON and a file to web service with Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203145/how-to-post-json-and-a-file-to-web-service-with-angular) i am tried this link but this throw bad request error`enter code here`[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203145/how-to-post-json-and-a-file-to-web-service-with-angular)

this is my angular 2 code

```
runImportRecordsJob(importRecords: any){
  let options = new RequestOptions();

  let formData = new FormData();
  let f={
    'country':"india",
    'bug':"bug",
  };

  formData.append("file", importRecords.file, importRecords.file.name);
  formData.append("data",f);

  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', undefined);

  return this.http.post(this.constantService.URL+'/data/fileupload',formData,{
    headers: headers}).map(this.constantService.extractData)
  .catch(this.constantService.handleError);
}
```

This is spring rest webservice

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/data/fileupload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postFile(@RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file,
                   @RequestParam(value="data") Object data) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("data = " + data);

  return "OK!";
}
```

When trying to call this web service it give me error Bad Request error

Comment: Did you test the webservice from postman? I think it has some problem. RequestParam is used to bind variable from query parameter. I hope you are getting the values in request body. So it is not required to be defined with RequestParam.

Comment: as @notionquest pointed please try and check your restful api with postman first

Comment: i have tried on postman it give me same error bad request and General RLG Exception